# Imprimir árbol binario en C (gráficamente)

Tags: c, árboles-binarios

Tengo el siguiente código, que imprime árboles de forma "gráfica", el problema es que, en vez de imprimirme los caracteres correspondientes a los valores ASCII: 179, 192, 195, 196.
Me imprime otros caracteres.

```
    void imprimirArbol(NodoArbol* a, char cade[])
{
    printf("%s\n", a->info);
    if(a->izq!=NULL)
    {
        char cad2[1000];
        strcpy(cad2, cade);
        if(a->der)
        {
            printf("%s%c%c%c%c%c", cade, 195, 196, 196, 196, 196);
            char simb = 179, aux[2];
            aux[0] = simb; aux[1] = '\0';
            strcat(cad2, aux);
            strcat(cad2, "     ");
            imprimirArbol(a->izq, cad2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s%c%c%c%c%c", cade, 192, 196, 196, 196, 196);
            strcat(cad2,"     ");
            imprimirArbol(a->izq, cad2);
        }
    }

    if(a->der!=NULL)
    {
        char cad3[1000];
        strcpy(cad3, cade);
        printf("%s%c%c%c%c%c", cade, 192, 196, 196, 196, 196);
        strcat(cad3, "     ");
        imprimirArbol(a->der, cad3);
    }
}
```

Adjunto foto del resultado de corrida del código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven también he impreso mi árbol en PostOrden para verificar que se estaba generando bien, y los espacios separan cada nodo del árbol. Las comas solo son separadores de términos, en realidad no guarda eso en el árbol.
También incluyo aquí abajo la declaración de mis nodos de ABB:

```
typedef struct na{
    char *info;
    struct na *der, *izq;
} NodoArbol;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se muestran esos caracteres por la codificación usada por la consola, que supongo es [UTF-8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), sugiero que establezcas la codificación UTF-8 en tu editor y uses los caracteres literales en lugar de códigos de caracter solo incluidos en la [Página de códigos 437](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_437). Por ejemplo:

```c
if(a->der)
{
    printf("%s├───", cade);
    strcat(cad2, "│");
    strcat(cad2, "     ");
    imprimirArbol(a->izq, cad2);
}
```

Se evade el uso de `char aux[2]` porque un caracter especial en UTF-8 puede ocupar más de un único valor `char`.